# Updating same flag twice using MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `chart` with two columns, named `UPC_REPORT_ID` and `UPC_FLAG`
I am trying to prepare a query to update a `UPC_FLAG=1` if `UPC_REPORT_ID=1` and simultaneously I want to update `UPC_FLAG=0` where `UPC_REPORT_ID !=2`
Please give me the suggestions

Comment: All rows satisfying `UPC_REPORT_ID=1` will also satisfy `UPC_REPORT_ID !=2` condition. Eventually all `UPC_FLAG` will be set to a same value

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE chart SET UPC_FLAG = (CASE WHEN UPC_REPORT_ID=1 THEN 1 ELSE CASE WHEN UPC_REPORT_ID !=2 THEN 0 END END)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE chart
SET UPC_FLAG = CASE UPC_REPORT_ID
                    WHEN 1 THEN 1
                    WHEN 2 then UPC_FLAG
                    ELSE 0
               END
```

Answer (score 0):

Use WHEN

UPDATE ...   set UPC_FLAG=CASE WHEN UPC_REPORT=1 THEN 1 WHEN UPC_REPORT_ID <> 2 THEN 0 END WHERE...

--dmg

Answer (score 0):

The same thing with IF AS Barmar's answer

```
UPDATE chart
SET UPC_FLAG = IF(UPC_REPORT_ID = 1,1,IF(UPC_REPORT_ID <> 2,2,0))
```